# prime number theorem equivalence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Well, I'm far away of understanding the proof of the prime number theorem. But I have this stupid question:

How can I show this equivalence:

$\pi (x) \thicksim \frac{x}{ \log (x) } \iff p_n \thicksim n \cdot \log (n) $

Where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number and $\pi(x)$ is the prime number counting function, that means $\pi(x) = |\{n \in \mathbb{N} : (n \le x)  \land (n \text{ is prime})\}|$

Thank you for your help.

Regards, Sandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weak version of the PNT states that for any $x$ big enough
$$ \frac{c_1 x}{\log x}\leq \pi(x) \leq \frac{c_2 x}{\log x} $$
with $c_1<1<c_2$ and $c_1+c_2=2$. Since $\pi(p_n)=n$, it follows that
$$ \frac{c_1 p_n}{\log p_n} \leq n \leq \frac{c_2 p_n}{\log p_n} $$
hence
$$ c_1 p_n \leq n \log p_n \leq n\log\left(n\cdot\frac{\log p_n}{c_1}\right)=n\log(n)\left(1+o(1)\right)$$
and similarly $c_2 p_n = n\log n(1+o(1)) $, hence $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$ implies $p_n\sim n\log n$.
On the other hand, if we know that $\pi(n\log n)\sim n$, then
$$ \pi(m)\sim\frac{m}{W(m)} $$
where $W$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and for large values of $m$ we have $W(m)\sim \log(m)$ since $xe^x = e^{x+o(1)}$.

Comment: Erratum: Second Line
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{c_1 p_n}{\log p_n} \leq n \leq \frac{c_2 \color{red}{p_n}}{\log p_n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Please delete this comment when amended.

Answer (score 2):

$\pi(n) \approx n/\ln(n)$.  That means of the numbers 1... $n$  roughly $1/\ln(n)$ are primes, or in other words primes occur on average $\ln (n)$ units apart.  So $p_n$ being the $n$th prime is roughly $n*\ln(n)$.

Comment: Small edit, "the $\rm \bf{probability}$ of finding a prime in the range $1..n $ is $1/\ln(n)$", not that there are $1/\ln(n)$ primes (assuming primes are sprinkled uniformly). However there seems to be a flaw here. In the argument, primes occur $\ln (n)$ units apart on average, and there are $\pi(n)$ primes in the range $1.. n $, where $\pi(n)$ is less than $n$.

Comment: Continued...The first $n$ in the formula $n \ln(n) $ comes from counting the $n$'th prime number and must be from the range $1 .. \pi(n) $, since there are only $\pi(n)$ primes available from $1$ up to $n$. The second $n $ in the formula $n \ln (n)$, representing the number of units apart primes are sprinkled, is from the range $1.. n $. Should we use the same $n$ for different ranges?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\pi(x) \sim x/\ln(x)
$$
basically says that if you take the first $x$ integers and start iterating through them (starting at $1$) then roughly every $\ln(x)$ number you will find a prime number. This can also be seen as the probabilty of a particular number in $\{1,...,x\}$ to be prime is $1/\ln(x)$ since you know there are $\pi(x)$ prime number in this set and the size of the set is $x$ : $probability = good\_case/total\_case = \pi(x) / x \sim 1/\ln(x)$.

Therefore if you want to have the $n$'th prime number you will have to iterate through $n \ln(n)$ numbers before seening it.

Comment: Yes, that's a good intuition. But how can I prove this formally?

Comment: "then roughly every ln(x) number you will find a prime number"  I'd quibble and say roughly on average the prime numbers are ln(x) apart as we know they are not evenly distributed.

Comment: @S.M.Roch  Prove *what* formally?

Comment: I would like so see a proof that uses the definition $a_n \thicksim b_n :\iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$. Honestly, I'm not so familiar with the $\thicksim$ symbol.

Comment: There seems to be a flaw in the reasoning here. In the argument, primes occur on average $\ln (n)$ units apart, and there are by definition $\pi(n)$ primes in the range $1.. n $ where $\pi(n)$ is strictly less than $n$. The first $n$ in the formula $n \ln(n) $ comes from counting the $n$'th prime number and must be in the range $1 .. \pi(n) $, since there are only $\pi(n)$ primes available from $1$ up to $n$. The second $n $ in the formula $n \ln (n)$, representing the number of units apart primes are sprinkled, is from the range $1.. n $. Should we use the same $n$ for different ranges?